# Div does not consume all the height of the parent

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div which is root, parent, child items.

The root min-height is set to 350px, however the parent does not consuming all the 350px.

I tried to add a flex-grow: 1 in the parent container but it shows the following error: The display: block property on the parent element prevents flex-grow from having an effect.
Try setting the display: block property on the parent to display: flex.

This is my code:

CSS:

```
.root {
  min-height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
 }

.item {
    height: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS CODE is missing `html,body{height:100%;}` so `.root` can inherit height:100% from the view  through html then body.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you can try using `display: flex` for the `root` div element.

```
.root {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
}
```